# There is a way to ping a Docker container using its hostname, from another Docker Container?

Tags: docker, ping, hostname

I am looking for a solution to ping a Docker container using its hostname, from another Docker Container.
I tried as follow:

starting first Docker container:

```
docker run --rm -ti --hostname=repohost --name=repo repo
```

starting second Docker container, link to first and start bash:

```
docker run --rm -ti --hostname=repo2host --link repo:rp repo2 /bin/bash
```

on bash started on repo2

```
ping repohost
```

it remain on pending without any result.

Can someone tell me if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to ping using the alias you gave in the link command (the part after the `:`), in your case `ping rp` should work.

The following works for me, given a running container called furious_turing:

`$ docker run -it --link furious_turing:ft debian /bin/bash
root@06b18931d80b:/# ping ft
PING ft (172.17.0.3): 48 data bytes
56 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.136 ms
56 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
56 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.092 ms
^C--- ft ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.091/0.106/0.136/0.000 ms
root@06b18931d80b:/#`

If you need to ping on another name, you can add entries to `/etc/hosts` with the `--add-host` argument to `docker run`.

Comment: I know this way, but  I need to use the hostname for my specific  purpose.

Comment: It would have helped if you explained that :) I've added a mention of --add-host, but I'm not sure it will help. Perhaps you could explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I don' t know if it is helpfull, but I try to crate a spark cluster (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) for developement using Docker and Docker Compose.

Comment: What I mean is, why can't you just use the hostname as the alias? i.e.  `--link repo:repohost`

Comment: I just tried it , but it seems dosen't work when contact the master host on boostrap spark slave. Latter requires the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you need would be with [WeaveDNS](https://github.com/zettio/weave/blob/master/weavedns/README.md).

Comment: _Disclamer: I am from Weave team._